# Difference between customizing form theme and referencing block in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

what is the difference between referencing a widget block and customizing it : the docs say :

> So far, to override a particular form block, the best method is to
>   copy the default block from form_div_layout.html.twig, paste it into a
>   different template, and then customize it. In many cases, you can
>   avoid doing this by referencing the base block when customizing it

But to me it looks the same :

```
{# app/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block integer_widget %}
    <div class="integer_widget">
        {{ parent() }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}




{# app/Resources/views/form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block integer_widget %}
    <div class="integer_widget">
        {% set type = type|default('number') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first example in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template)  that you are referencing shows how to override the entire widget that displays your form element.

The [second example in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#referencing-base-form-blocks-twig-specific) that you are referencing  shows how you can employ code re-use so that you are not rewriting form templating sections that you are not modifying.  So, instead of having to declare

```
    {% set type = type|default('number') %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
```

all over again in your overriding widget, you can instead reference the base block that already has this.  If you are [referencing base blocks from an external template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#referencing-base-blocks-from-an-external-template), you can call the parent block via `{{ parent() }}`, and if you are [referencing blocks from inside the same template as the form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#referencing-blocks-from-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form), you can call the base block via `{{ block('base_integer_widget') }}`

If you look at it from a PHP/Symfony point of view with inheritance that can help explain it as well.  Say you have one PHP class that extends another and you want to override a function named `doSomething()` - you might rewrite the entire function as you need it.  But, say that `doSomething()` has a block of common code that you always want to run, then you might perform your actions and call `parent::doSomething()` at the end of it.  Or, if you're accessing a different Symfony service you might call `$this->get('some.service')->doSomething()` instead.

That's the same concept here, you can either override the entire widget or you can override parts of it - perhaps putting a surrounding `<div></div>` but calling  `{{ parent() }}` from within that since you're changing nothing else about the widget.

I do have one example where I overrode standard button behavior in Symfony and used both cases.  I have a separate template file in `app/Resources/views/Form/navigationButton.html.twig' with the following code:

```
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block button_widget -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default(''))|trim}) %}
    {{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock %}

{% block button_row -%}
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
{%- endblock button_row %}
```

I am overriding the button widget by allowing additional classes to be passed as attributes and then calling the parent widget to produce it as normal.  I then override the button row widget to not put surrounding `<div></div>` tags since I didn't want that in my template (see the originals [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L184) and [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L252)).

Then to use in one of my templates I simply do:

```
{% form_theme form ':Form:navigationButton.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example where you declare the widget all over again and where you're using parent()?

Comment: I edited my post to include more explanation plus example code.